# Arbitrary dimension for CVXGEN program

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, hessian-matrix, cvx

I would like to solve a QP/LP problem in `MatLab` using `CVXGEN`.  I have preference for `CVXGEN` over `CVX`, since `CVXGEN` is much faster.  In particular, I would like to solve

```
min f(x) s.t. x in X
```

where `f(x)` is in quadratic form and `X` is compact, convex, and defined by linear functions.  The size of the problem varies depending on the run.  I would like to automate the procedure as much as possible.  To illustrate, an example of a  `CVXGEN` code is:

```
dimensions
  n = 10  
end

parameters
  Q (n,n) psd  # quadratic penalty.
end

variables
  x (n)
end

minimize
  quad(x, Q)
end​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

​This code is inputted at `cvxgen.com`.  On this website, I can then generate the C code which gives me a unique number.  I can then compile this into MEX code using the unique number.  Last, I can call this MEX code (`csolve`) from MatLab by running the following code

```
n=10; % dimension of the problem
params.Q = eye(n,n); % assume that the Hessian is the identity
[vars, status] = csolve(params); % this outputs optimal x* = 0.
```

This procedure, however, requires for each dimension of the problem `n` that I want to run, I need to go to `cvxgen.com`, change `n`, compile code, then run my `MatLab` code.  Is it possible to let `n` enter as a parameter?  This way, I only need to compile the code once, then in my `MatLab` code set `params.n = n` and `params.Q = eye(n,n)`, and then call `[vars, status] = csolve(params);`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I do not think it is possible to specify arbitrary dimension on `cvxgen.com`.  I do have one solution: First, in MatLab, allow the user to specify his/her email address and password for `cvxgen.com`. Next, using `system` command in `MatLab`, call a `python` or `javascript` program that executes the following steps:

1) Log user into `cvxgen.com`

2) Goto `edit` tab on website

3) Copy and paste the `cvxgen` code

4) Goto `generate c` tab

5) Click `generate code`

6) Goto `matlab` tab

7) Copy unique identifying number for the compiled C code to be downloaded

8) Pass the unique identifying number back to `MatLab` and compile the `Mex` files in `MatLab` by calling the identifying number.

Now the `Mex` files can be called in `MatLab` by the following commands:

```
n=10; % dimension of the problem
params.Q = eye(n,n); % assume that the Hessian is the identity
[vars, status] = csolve(params); % this outputs optimal x* = 0.
```